# Tor doesn't read the torrc file

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, onion-routing

When I tried to create a .onion service by modifying the torrc file, nothing happened. I mean nothing. The official website says that if tor is not starting then there is a problem. Well tor is starting and there isn't any information in the embedded logs about an error. When I enabled saving logs in the torrc file, nothing changed. No logs were generated in /var/log/tor. Any help?

Comment: You tagged this with `tor-browser-bundle`. Are you trying to run your onion service using the tor that runs with Tor Browser? Or are you using the tor daemon (ex: `apt install tor`)?

Comment: I tried to make an onion service with the tor browser

Comment: You need to add more information to your question about exactly what files you're editing, what their contents are, and what commands you're running. It sounds like you're modifying the wrong torrc file, and the Tor Browser doesn't log to /var/log.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a hidden service by following the instructions at https://community.torproject.org/onion-services/setup/ The command to restart tor after changing torrc is

```
sudo systemctl restart tor
```